# Multiple theads access Memcache

Tags: java, multithreading, memcached

What happen if multiple thread access the same object which stored in memcached ??

I have a object say ObjStore which stored in memcached.

each thread retrieve the ObjStore from memcached and change something and again store to memcached.

At the same time in another module if I want to fetch the same object ObjStore from memcached, sometimes it is return empty object.

I am using memcache 1.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

Memcached hold only last version of object. If you get, modify and put you have no guarantee that the put applies to the same value as the get. You could use CAS operations (`gets`, `cas`) if you need to synchronize.

Comment: but memcached synchronization makes application slower.

Comment: But in most cases you don't need to synchronize cache.